# Unable to autosize the label inside the UITableView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I have added a label inside a `UITableCell`. Now the label can have dynamic content based on the server response. So I want to set the height of label based on the content in the label. When the text increases it should be in multi lines. So far I have tried these but nothing works.

```
cell.label_like_count.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.label_like_count.numberOfLines = 0;
[cell.label_like_count sizeToFit];
NSString *first_like_user=@"Some Name rtyrtytyt";
int count=[first_like_user length];
NSString *like_count=@"12";
like_count=[like_count stringByAppendingString:@" others like your post"];
first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" and "];
first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:like_count];
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:first_like_user];

NSAttributedString *attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

[mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

[mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];

cell.label_like_count.attributedText = mutableAttributeStr;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(187,9999);
CGSize requiredSize = [cell.label_like_count sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
CGRect labelFrame = cell.label_like_count.frame;
labelFrame.size.height = requiredSize.height;
cell.label_like_count.frame = labelFrame;

[cell.label_like_count setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
```

Comment: give width contraint and line break as word wrap to the label!!!!

Comment: i have given lined break

Comment: You need to increase your UITableviewcell height also.

Comment: can somebody suggest me exact code for this ?

Comment: You have to set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` on the UILabel to the width of the area you want text to wrap in. If you are using auto layout, all you should need are the proper constraints and this property set as the height should be getting calculated automatically. So all you should have is create cell, set cell properties and autolayout should do the rest. If it does not work then chances are your constraints are not right.

Comment: can you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

iOS8 and above:

1. Add label to cell's **content** view
2. Snap **all** label's edges to content's view edges
3. Set `label.numberOfLines = 0;`
4. Set `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`
5. Set `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = your_cell_average_height;`